# pull data from a file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

please help to pull data from a file fruits.json

html:

```
    <body ng-app="fruitsApp">
        <div ng-controller="fruitsController">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">{{fruit.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
```

js:

```
var fruitsApp = angular.module('fruitsApp', [])

fruitsApp.factory('fruitsFactory', function($http) {
  return {
          $http.get('fruits.json').success(callback);
      }
  };
});

fruitsApp.controller('fruitsController', function($scope, fruitsFactory) {
  fruitsFactory.getFruitsAsync(function(results) {
      $scope.fruits = results.fruits;
  });
});
```

fruits.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "qwerty", 
        "date": "12.11.2012", 
        "teaser": "1Вас научат пользоваться им, дадут советы по эксплуатации и покажут возможности того, что Вы приобрели.", 
        "body": "Вас научат пользоваться им, дадут советы по эксплуатации и покажут возможносто"
    }]
```

lice demo:
http://prozaik.16mb.com/angular/remote_data_2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 mistake in your factory declaration. There is no method `getFruitsAsync` (which you trying to use in controller). Declare it inside return {} as property = function.

2 mistake: you don't have field 'fruits' in response, your response is array, so `$scope.fruits = results.fruits;` should be `$scope.fruits = results;`

Answer (score 1):

You code should be something like this (not tested):

```
var fruitsApp = angular.module('fruitsApp', [])

fruitsApp.factory('fruitsFactory', function($http) {
  return {
          getFruitsAsync: function(callback) {
              $http.get('fruits.json').success(callback);
          }
      }
  };
});

fruitsApp.controller('fruitsController', function($scope, fruitsFactory) {
  fruitsFactory.getFruitsAsync(function(results) {
      $scope.fruits = results;
  });
});
```